# libPhoneNumber not giving correct US results on edittext

Tags: android, libphonenumber

I am trying to create an edit text with a text watcher that displays the phone number correctly, to start out I am just testing it with a US number.

If I go to this site
http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/
And type in US and the number 9188143287 the results look perfect however when I implement the library as they say I am getting different results

Here is my fragment

```
ublic class PhoneNumberFragment extends Fragment{

private TextView next;
private EditText phoneNumber;
private PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil;
private AsYouTypeFormatter formatter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_phone_number, container, false);
    phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    formatter = phoneUtil.getAsYouTypeFormatter("US");



    init(v);



    return v;
}
private void init(View v){
    next = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
    phoneNumber = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);

    phoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberTextWatcher());




}

private void turnOnNext(){
    next.setBackgroundResource(R.color.warningRed);
}

private class PhoneNumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

    private boolean isFormatting = false;


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
        // TODO: implement your code
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO: implement your code
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                           int count) {
        if(before > count) {
            return;
        }


        if(!isFormatting) {
            isFormatting = true;
            try {
                formatter.clear();
                for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++) {
                    phoneNumber.setText(formatter.inputDigit(s.charAt(i)));
                    phoneNumber.setSelection(phoneNumber.getText().length());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {}
            isFormatting = false;
        }
    }

}

}
```

My results are correct up to 7 digits, but then on the 8th digit the brackets are supposed to appear around the first 3 and they do not.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: pls show screenshots of 7 digits and 8 digits entered

Comment: Sure thing, just added them

Comment: please also show the expected result. At least the text string